# Mysterious Timer

Tags: electrical, timer

We just rented a place and there is this timer on the wall in the hallway. As far as I can tell it does absolutely nothing, any ideas what it is for?

The timer is fairly close to our laundry closet, which does contain an exhaust fan, perhaps the two are related.

[edit]

*As pointed out in the comments, this question doesn't really fit here and should probably be removed, since it "can't be answered".

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this question. Wouldn't it make more sense to ask a neighbor, or the landlord, or the super, instead of a bunch of ding dongs an internet away?

Comment: My neighbors keep to themselves and the the ladies working in the office didn't know...hence the question.   Isn't that the purpose of this site??? To ask questions?

Comment: The purpose of the site is to ask questions **that can be answered**.  There's no way to answer this question without being at (or having been at) your apartment. Every answer will be a complete guess.

Comment: So instead of being condescending why not just say that? Instead of some snide remark?

Comment: Snide remarks are how we communicate in my culture. Maybe I need to be more conscience of my cross cultural communication. I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: It's okay, I forgive you! lol - Wasn't trying to be an ass. :)

Comment: Yeah! We ding dongs are offended!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely depends on where you live, but where I live, these are required by code to control an exhaust fan somewhere in the house. This is a (IMHO) silly code requirement that was implemented to combat 'tight houses' in the 90s and force a level of air exchange.

Ideally, today, we'd use actual air exchanges.

As to whether your timer is connected to a vent is hard to say. Maybe it was a one time but was taken out?

Alternative theories:

- sprinkler system timer
- exterior lights timer
- attic fan timer

Comment: Wasn't sure if it was related but now I think it might be. There is an exhaust fan in the closet with our washer and dryer which is right next to the timer, but, there is a 60 minute timer in the closet that controls the fan, perhaps this was used previously. It's an apartment so I doubt we'd have control over anything major. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

The arrow points to the time of day. Then a metal "pin" is placed in the slots around the perimeter, one for on and one for off.

In this case the pins are missing, and I highly doubt you'll find replacements as this timer and design is a good few years old. I haven't seen one of these for sale new in a while.

Right now the only function is the black button on the top right which is the on/off override.